# Multiple feature branches that need to introduce their own migrations - Alembic

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, database-migration, alembic

Our team is using Python's Alembic in conjunction with SQLAlchemy as our DB migration tool. Say there are two developers and two feature branches are created from a parent branch called `feature1` and `feature2`. If:

1. Dev1 **creates and runs** a migration on the `feature1` branch and some time later dev2 decides he also needs to create and run a migration. However, dev2 will **fail** when creating the migration since the down revision no longer matches the one marked in the database after dev1 had ran his migration: `FAILED: Can't locate revision identified by <last_migration_ran's_id>`
2. If dev1 and dev2 created a migration at the same time and dev1 ran the migration, dev2 will face the same issue above.

Is there a solution to this type of problem where multiple devs need to work on their own feature branches that alters the same database with alembic?
The mechanism that's in place that seems to prevent any migrations from being created or ran if it doesn't match the migration marked in the Alembic table - but I can see how this can prevent issues where multiple devs need to alter the same tables/columns/etc. in which a collaborative measure needs to be taken.

But overall, this seems like general issue where careful measure need be taken to prevent unpredictable outcomes when migrations from different feature branches are merged back in and ran at different times.

Any guidance would be extremely helpful as I am still a novice at this type of stuff.

These two stackoverflow threads pretty much detail the dilemma I am facing:

- [Work on multiple branches with Flask-Migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55715129/work-on-multiple-branches-with-flask-migra)
- [Using Flyway with multiple feature-branches that change the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618511/using-flyway-with-multiple-feature-branches-that-change-the-same-object?rq=3)

Comment: You can start by giving each dev their own test database. Ultimately, each test run should start with a clean test environment to prevent any number of interactions between branches, devs, and test runs. Your project should have a procedure to create a clean test environment with a single command. Branches should share no resources before they are merged.